# Transforming a matrix valued differential equation to a single complex equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I did not know how to formulate a better title, my apologies!

Given a matrix valued function $A: \mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2x2}, t\mapsto A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
cos(t) & -sin(t) \\
sin(t) & cos(t) \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I want to find the solution to the differential equation $$\begin{cases}
      u'(t)=A(t)u(t)& \text{for}\ t \geq 0 \\
      u(0)= (1,0)
    \end{cases} $$

Normally I'd use general solution and just "plug it in", i.e. 
$$u(t)=e^{(t)A}u_0$$

That should be a solution $u(t)=(u_1(t),u_2(t))$, but it was given as a hint that one can calculate the solution by ( and I quote ) transforming the real system of equations to a single complex equation $z'(t)=c(t)z(t)$ with a carefully chosen function $c:\mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ where $z(t)=u_1(t)+iu_2(t)$

So we have $$(u_1(t)+iu_2(t))' = c(t)(u_1(t)+iu_2(t))$$

But to be able to solve for $c(t)$ I have to know $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$, and if I did, I'd already have the solution... How is that helpful?

Furthermore, if I convert it to a complex equation I basically don't know how to differentiate / integrate anymore, as this is a real analysis course and complex numbers were barely introduced, differentiation and integration for complex numbers was never talked about.

**Could somebody elaborate on the "hint"? How is this helpful and how do you go about converting it to such a complex equation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to translate the real $2\times 2$ $A(t)$ to a complex scalar $c(t)$:

As suggested, we identify the first compenent of $u$ with the real part of a complex function and the second with a the imaginary part.

So we have $$A(t)u(t)=\begin{pmatrix}u_1(t) \cos(t) - u_2(t)\sin(t) \\u_2 \sin(t) + u_2 \cos(t)\end{pmatrix}.$$

On the other hand, if we write $c(t)=x(t) + i y(t)$, we have

$$c(t)(u_1(t)+iu_2(t))=x(t)u_1(t) - y(t)u_1(t) + i(x(t)u_2(t) + y(t)u_2(t)).$$

Which choice of $x(t),y(t)$ allows us to identify the first component of $Au$ with the real part and the second component with the imaginary part of the expression above?

Note that $z'(t)=c(t)z(t)$ is still a differential equation with a real free variable $t$, this is still real analysis (with complex coefficients, though).

Comment: This was of tremendous help, thank you. So $c(t)= e^{it} $ and I found the solution of the complex differential equation to be $z(t)=c \cdot \exp{(\int_0^t e^{ix}dx)} =c \cdot \exp{(\sin(t)+i(-\cos(t)+1))} $

If this is correct the solution to the original problem should be $u(t)=(u_1(t),u_2(t))=(\Re(z(t),\Im(z(t))$ alas the real and imaginary part should correspond to the respective components. But how does one separate the real and imaginary part?